# why my tcp syn message doesn't get tcp syn ack so i cant connect to server

Tags: c, networking, ip, tcpclient, ethernet

i wrote a C code which is in an Embedded system. Clients can connect to me but i can't connect servers since they don't reply with syn ack back. In fact, they do nothing at all. Here is the frame(first 5 is the mac of my PC so i replaced them with 00):

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 12 48 07 06 20 03 08 00 45 00 00 34 E2 44 40
00 80 06 00 00 A9 FE 19 FC A9 FE 19 FE 00 50 1F 90 00 BC 61 4E
00 00 00 00 80 02 FA F0 8A 16 00 00 02 04 FF D7 01 03 03 08 01
01 04 02  //old hex bytes new below
```

Hi everyone. It is me back again. I ' ve reviewed the comments & answers, as as a result of that i have changed my code. Now i am trying to connect to my pc(server socket HERCULES 8080 port is being listened) my embedded system(client) via router. Also i found out my checksum calculation was wrong. I fixed it according to RFC 1071. I still can't get SYN ACK message after my SYN attempt. I am sharing new ethernet frame below(new answers are after 09.09.2021):

80 fa 5b 90 bf 5c 12 48 07 06 20 03 08 00 45 00
00 34 b4 00 40 00 80 06 00 00 c0 a8 01 6d c0 a8
01 64 00 50 1f 90 87 65 43 21 00 00 00 00 80 02
ff ff 06 64 00 00 02 04 ff d7 01 03 03 08 01 01
04 02

you can decode @: https://hpd.gasmi.net/ gives the same result as wireshark

Comment: i have studied ethernet, ip and tcp frames before i started. After failing i have compared mine with other TCP SYN examples through wireshark.

Comment: Did you check whether the SYN is received by _the PC_ and whether _the PC_ responds with something else, as an ICMP message?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i can ping with ICMP. How do i check if SYN is received by PC? I can see it on wireshark. Also i can connect to my embedded system but i want to use my embedded system as client now.

Answer (score 1):

Your IP is 169.254.25.252 which is within the Automatic Private Internet Protocol Addressing range.
This range is not routed on internet and you'll never get a reply

Salim

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Thanks. I connected my Embedded system directly to the PC via Ethernet. As a result of this i used the similiar IP adress. So, I didn't receive any i just wrote my IP address(not using dhcp for now). I will try this via Router(has 192.168.1.1 default) I also use Hercules but i can connect by its client port to server port by using 169.254.25.252

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Copying hercules SYN frame was a mistake for me. I thought IPv4 header checksum must have been 0. However, when i corrected that frame it works properly now.